# Unable to find TermRangeQuery in hibernate-search 6

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

I am not able to find below class in hibernate-search 6

*import org.apache.lucene.search.TermRangeQuery;*

is there any similar class available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an Apache Lucene class, not a Hibernate Search class. And this class still exists in the version of Lucene (8) used by Hibernate Search 6, so I don't understand what your problem is exactly.

In any case... you should probably use the Hibernate Search DSL, and the [range predicate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl-predicate-range).